# Make login from central domain and redirect to tenant with tenancyforlaravel package

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I want to make multitenant solution with multiple databases (one DB per tenant). Central domain for instance example.com has things like registration form and login form e.g example.com/sign-in
Each customer is a new tenant identified by sub domain e.g foo.example.com

**Sign in process (happy scenario)**

1. User see view called e.g sign-in on central domain
2. User fill email and password
3. System check if credentials are correct
4. System will redirect authenticated user to his tenant domain e.g foo.example.com
5. System will show dashboard view with data of that authenticated user. Dashboard is behind auth middleware.

I have decided to use this library: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/
Everything is working, I have created tenant, central domain is also working. My issue is, that if I want to log user from central domain, after redirection to his tenant domain, I get 403 Unauthenticated.

Here is a example code of tenant.php

```
    Route::middleware([
    'web',
    InitializeTenancyBySubdomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    
    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
      Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return 'Tenant' . tenant('id');
      });
    });

});
```

I put `Auth::Routes();` into `web.php`. I am using Laravel's UI Auth.

What I am missing? Thank you very much for help.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I am trying to accomplish the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: @Masiorama I didn't solve it. I had to move login form to subdomain. If you will solve it, please inform me, how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: mmm I somehow managed to configure to do login from the central domain and share the session with subdomains, and in the middleware I can check if the user si logged in or has permission to access the subdomain... dunno if this sounds promising or not...

Comment: Hi ! did you solve this? do you have a central app UI to share?

Comment: @matiazar I did't solve it. Instead, I have made custom middleware, which is setting proper database connection based on login data from user.

Comment: and what if you have 2 tenants with same user name (email) ?

Comment: @matiazar sorry, I have forgotten mention, that I have third login information - company code. Without that, it wouldn ´t work. So, data for instance: 100, j.doe@example.com, somePassword. Based on this information I will check if user exists in particular company . If so, I will get db connection from main db and set the new connection in middleware, based on data which I have obtained. I have REST API, so than I can use middleware with new user connection in api.php for routes, which I want to use the new connection.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to use feature "synced resources between tenants" be able to keep your user data synced between central and tenant DB's:
https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/synced-resources-between-tenants/

Then user auth could be done via "Impersonation" feature:
https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/features/user-impersonation/